# Accessing a dictionary using another variable as key YAML

Tags: ansible, yaml

My requirements are these: a deployment environment is passed into the playbook as extra vars, for ex : dev, qa or prod

I have a variable called DEPLOY_URL

Based on the value of the env variable, the DEPLOY_URL has to change.

I tried doing the following :

```
DEPLOY_URLS: 
   "dev": "xyz"
   "prod" : "abc"
   "qa" : "123"

DEPLOY_URL: "{{DEPLOY_URLS['{{DEPLOY_ENV}}']}}"
```

The value is never correct.
Is there a way to access a dictionary using another variable as key? 
(Using YAML and ansible)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Try this: `DEPLOY_URL: "{{ DEPLOY_URLS[DEPLOY_ENV] }}"`

Comment: That works!!!! Thank you! Can I ask how it works though? I thought {{}} was required for variables

Comment: With `{{` you start jinja2 [expression](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#expressions). You should reference variables by name inside of expressions.